# PathTooLongException after migrating from ASP.NET MVC 1 to ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I had updated my app from MVC 1 to MVC 2. After that some pages throws `PathTooLongException`:

```
[PathTooLongException: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.]
   System.IO.Path.SafeSetStackPointerValue(Char* buffer, Int32 index, Char value) +7493057
   System.IO.Path.NormalizePathFast(String path, Boolean fullCheck) +387
   System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck) +36
   System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path) +21
   System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CanonicalizePath(String path, Boolean needFullPath) +73
   System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CreateListFromExpressions(String[] str, Boolean needFullPath) +278
   System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList) +87
   System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String path) +65
   System.Web.InternalSecurityPermissions.PathDiscovery(String path) +29
   System.Web.HttpRequest.MapPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, VirtualPath baseVirtualDir, Boolean allowCrossAppMapping) +146
   System.Web.HttpRequest.MapPath(VirtualPath virtualPath) +37
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage) +43
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) +28
   System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext) +284
   System.Web.Mvc.WebFormView.RenderViewPage(ViewContext context, ViewPage page) +82
   System.Web.Mvc.WebFormView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +85
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +267
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +320
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +104
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4() +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +53
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +7
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8678910
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

I know the issue with 260-character-url-lenght in ASP.NET, but my app works fine before update to ASP.NET MVC 2.0!

**This problem occurs not only locally but on a remote hosting too**

I compare `RenderView` method implementations.

MVC 1:

```
public virtual void RenderView(ViewContext viewContext) {
    ViewContext = viewContext;
    InitHelpers();
    // Tracing requires Page IDs to be unique.
    ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
}
```

MVC 2:

```
public virtual void RenderView(ViewContext viewContext) {
    ViewContext = viewContext;
    InitHelpers();

    bool needServerExecute = false;

    SwitchWriter switchWriter = viewContext.HttpContext.Response.Output as SwitchWriter;
    if (switchWriter == null) {
        switchWriter = new SwitchWriter();
        needServerExecute = true;
    }

    using (switchWriter.Scope(viewContext.Writer)) {
        if (needServerExecute) {
            // It's safe to reset the _nextId within a Server.Execute() since it pushes a new TraceContext onto
            // the stack, so there won't be an ID conflict.
            int originalNextId = _nextId;
            try {
                _nextId = 0;
                viewContext.HttpContext.Server.Execute(HttpHandlerUtil.WrapForServerExecute(this), switchWriter, true /* preserveForm */);
            }
            finally {
                // Restore the original _nextId in case this isn't actually the outermost view, since resetting
                // the _nextId may now cause trace ID conflicts in the outer view.
                _nextId = originalNextId;
            }
        }
        else {
            ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you also changed the (virtual) location of your project, or the folder where the Views are stored?

Comment: No, phisical project location have not been changed.

Answer (score 6):

This is more of an ASP.NET 4.0 default limit rather than ASP.NET MVC 1.0 to 2.0 migration issue. Try [increasing this limit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxurllength.aspx) in *web.config*:

```
<httpRuntime maxUrlLength="1000" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```

Comment: I use .NET 3.5 so i cant apply `maxUrlLength` and `relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping` to `httpRuntime` element into web.config.

Comment: This fixed a PathTooLong exception I was getting in HttpRequest.MapPath

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. It was caused by Spring.NET. `WebApplicationContext` works correctly with ASP.NET MVC 1.0. But couple `WebApplicationContext` + ASP.NET MVC 2.0 causes `PathTooLongException`. Now i just switch to `XmlApplicationContext` and all pages renders without errors.