# PathTooLongException when publishing MVC 4 app. The specified path, file name, or both are too long

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I am getting the following error when trying to publish my MVC 4 project using VS2012:

> Error 8   The "CollectFilesinFolder" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.IO.PathTooLongException: The specified path, file name, or both
>   are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260
>   characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
>   at System.IO.PathHelper.GetFullPathName()
>       at
>   System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32
>   maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
>       at
>   System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
>   at
>   System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CanonicalizePath(String path,
>   Boolean needFullPath)
>   at
>   System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CreateListFromExpressions(String[]
>   str, Boolean needFullPath)
>   at
>   System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess
>   access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean
>   checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
>   at
>   System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess
>   access, String path)
>   at System.IO.FileSystemInfo.get_FullName()

The error doesn't occur when building the solution (either debug or release) it just happens when publishing (file system).

I can't figure out which files, directory or path is causing the problem.

**How or where can I see what's causing the problem?**

Here is the output of my output window. I would appreciate any help to solve this issue. Thanks!

> Error 8   The "CollectFilesinFolder" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.IO.PathTooLongException: The specified path, file name, or both
>   are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260
>   characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
>   at System.IO.PathHelper.GetFullPathName()
>   at
>   System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32
>   maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
>   at
>   System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
>   at
>   System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CanonicalizePath(String path,
>   Boolean needFullPath)
>   at
>   System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CreateListFromExpressions(String[]
>   str, Boolean needFullPath)
>   at
>   System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess
>   access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean
>   checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
>   at
>   System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess
>   access, String path)
>   at System.IO.FileSystemInfo.get_FullName()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
>   rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result,
>   Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   excludeRelativePathMatchs)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
>   rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result,
>   Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   excludeRelativePathMatchs)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
>   rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result,
>   Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   excludeRelativePathMatchs)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
>   rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result,
>   Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   excludeRelativePathMatchs)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
>   rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result,
>   Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   excludeRelativePathMatchs)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
>   rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result,
>   Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   excludeRelativePathMatchs)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
>   rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result,
>   Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   excludeRelativePathMatchs)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
>   rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result,
>   Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   excludeRelativePathMatchs)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
>   rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result,
>   Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   excludeRelativePathMatchs)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
>   rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result,
>   Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   excludeRelativePathMatchs)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
>   rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result,
>   Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   excludeRelativePathMatchs)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
>   rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result,
>   Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   excludeRelativePathMatchs)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
>   rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result,
>   Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   excludeRelativePathMatchs)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
>   rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result,
>   Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   excludeRelativePathMatchs)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
>   rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result,
>   Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   excludeRelativePathMatchs)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
>   rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result,
>   Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   excludeRelativePathMatchs)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
>   rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result,
>   Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   excludeRelativePathMatchs)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
>   rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result,
>   Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   excludeRelativePathMatchs)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
>   rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result,
>   Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   excludeRelativePathMatchs)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
>   rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result,
>   Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   excludeRelativePathMatchs)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
>   rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result,
>   Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   excludeRelativePathMatchs)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
>   rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result,
>   Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[]
>   excludeRelativePathMatchs)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__20.MoveNext()     0   0   Nop.Web

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945808/pathtoolongexception-after-migrating-from-asp-net-mvc-1-to-asp-net-mvc-2

Answer (score 2):

This happens when your solution contains projects with very long names and/or has a lot of nested namespaces and/or is located in deep subfolder.

Try to move it closer to the root folder like X:\Projects\ or even X:. If this is not enough, you'll be forced to rename your namespaces

Comment: @SerhiyChuprk - Thanks for the suggestion. I tried moving it to the root folder but I got the same error. Regarding the namespaces, I'll check but the code is actually the source code from NopCommerce and I just added a couple of custom modifications so the namespaces haven't really changed. I am not sure what happened since this happened all of the sudden.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when publishing my ASP.NET Core MVC solution in VS2015. It turned out that inside [Solution name]\bin\Release\PublishOutput there was a rogue **bin** folder with the following contents:

> [Rogue bin
>   folder]\bin\Release\PublishOutput\bin\Release\PublishOutput...

I don't know for how long it went but I deleted it and the problem went away.